# Differential Equations; Find the solution to $y' + y/x = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I got as far as $v' -v/x = -1$ . I'm having trouble with the integrating factor (which I got was |x|), but I'm not sure how to implement that into the equation and get the answer. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The integrating factor would be $\frac{1}{x}$, would it not?

Comment: So from my understanding, to get the integrating factor, I would have to raise e to the integral of $1/x$ to get e raised to the ln|x| which just becomes |x| since ln and e cancel.. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are not integrating $1/x$; you are integrating $-1/x$, which produces a completely different result.

Comment: Ok, I re-did it, and it checks out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. Set $u = xy(x)$, then we see that
\begin{align}
u' = xy' + y
\end{align}
and it follows
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{-1}{u} \right)'=\frac{u'}{u^2}=\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{-1}{u} = \log|x|+C \ \ \implies  u = \frac{-1}{\log|x|+C}.
\end{align}
Equivalently, we see that
\begin{align}
y = \frac{-1}{x\log|x|+Cx}.
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't understand your way, but applying the correct integrating factor $-1/x$ yielded me with the same result as yours. Thank you.

Comment: @fusion_ow : The term combination $xy'+y$ is easy to recognize even with a factor and is equal to $(xy)'$, leading to above substitution.